# CMake version 3.13.2 using Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS

Tags: cmake

I have removed all CMAKE versions from my Ubuntu file directory.

But when i'm giving the command `cmake --version` I get that CMake version is 3.13.2.

How can I find the below cmake version in my file management system 
I used the find cmake command but I can't find any such filename.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Below is what I get when `cmake --version` command is executed.

```
sotos@sotos:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.13.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
sotos@sotos:~$
```

Comment: How did yoy installed cmake? What is the output of `apt list --installed | grep cmake`?

Comment: What i get after the execution of the below cmd  is:                       sotos@sotos:~$ apt list --installed|grep cmake

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

cmake-data/bionic,bionic,now 3.10.2-1ubuntu2 all [installed]

Comment: 1) I think I installed it using sudo apt-get install cmake-3.13.2.

Comment: You have cmake-data package installed. Remove that using `sudo apt autoremove cmake-data`

Comment: sotos@sotos:~$ sudo apt autoremove cmake-data Reading package lists... Done       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cmake-data
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 6743 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 241531 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cmake-data (3.10.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
sotos@sotos:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.13.2

Comment: I did but the the same result occurs...

Comment: finally i found the issue by find . -name cmake and then i deleted the folder were CMAKE 3.13.2 that was in .local/bin/Python2.7/